# Sqljob, make powershell step fail if file does not contain certain text

Tags: powershell, sql-job

This is an attempt to get a specific answer to a possible solution to [sqljob, on failed step, retry previous step, but not indefinitely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53037335/sqljob-on-failed-step-retry-previous-step-but-not-indefinitely)

I have a job, which transfer a file using 
`powershell -command "Invoke-WebRequest  https://someserver.dom/fetch.php -OutFile c:/tmp/data.xml"`

Sometime the data from upstream is not proper XML. I just want to "grep" for the final line in the file, if it is not the expected `</records>` I want the step to fail, so the step is retried a few times before it hard-fails.

The filesize could also be a error-criterium. A failed transfer is a few lines, a successfil is megabytes.

Comment: would you prefer checking if its just xml or that it ends in </records>

Comment: It is supposed to be xml, but I presume it would be easier just to assume if it ends with the usual </records> then the rest is probably OK.

Answer (score 1):

So basically i made a function just for this. Set the amount of attempts and the script to run.

```
function TryAgain($Attempts = 1, $Scriptblock){
    while($Attempts -gt 0){
        try{
            Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $Scriptblock
            Break
        }catch{
            $_.Exception
            $Attempts -= 1
        }
    }
}
```

In this case we want to find out if it is valid XML so we are going to get the `.RawContent` of the `Invoke-WebRequest` and test against `$(new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument).LoadXml()`. If it fails throw a error, if it passes then out the raw content to a file. Errors will not be saved to the file only valid XML

```
$Site = "https://someserver.dom/fetch.php"
$OutFile = "c:/test/data.xml"
(Invoke-WebRequest $Site).RawContent | %{
    try{
        $(new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument).LoadXml($_)
        $_ | out-file $OutFile
    }catch{
        throw "Bad XML"
    }
}
```

Now we combine into a final product

```
$Site = "https://someserver.dom/fetch.php"
$OutFile = "c:/test/data.xml"

function TryAgain($Attempts = 1, $Scriptblock){
    while($Attempts -gt 0){
        try{
            Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $Scriptblock
            Break
        }catch{
            $_.Exception
            $Attempts -= 1
        }
    }
}

TryAgain -Attempts 3 -Scriptblock {
    (Invoke-WebRequest $Site).RawContent | %{
        try{
            $(new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument).LoadXml($_)
            $_ | out-file $OutFile
        }catch{
            throw "Bad XML"
        }
    }
}
```

since you dont need the retries and all the glam here is it in basic

```
(Invoke-WebRequest https://someserver.dom/fetch.php).RawContent | %{
    try{
        (new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument).LoadXml($_)
        $_ | out-file C:\test\test.xml
    }catch{}
}
```

Comment: Looks impressive.
But is it overkill?
Can it just read the file, check for validity, then fail if not valid and let the sql-job handle retries, wait-times and hard fails?
I can on each step say it should retry n times and wait m seconds between retries.

Comment: I.e. just your second block? 
I suppose throwing "Bad XML" will tigger a failure exit on the step.
Anyway, it's 4AM, I'll try this tomorrow ;-)

Comment: You can just use the second block. I thought you needed retry on the webinvokes. I can also make it a one liner if ther  is no need to retry at this point

Comment: The sql-job handler can manage the retries, no need to complicate it by having the retries inside the step

Comment: Nice. Feedback in some hours

Comment: Sorry, had some issues. strangely, the powershell in sql agent does not seem to be the same as running in shell. So have to use "powershell cmdfile.ps1" in the command window. More info later